# Google Drive API vs. Browser Upload Very Slow

Tags: google-drive-api

When uploading a file using a web browser to Google Drive, the upload speed is very fast.  However, when using a tool like GoodSync that uses the Google Drive API, the speed seems capped at 600KBps, which is extremely slow.  I've contacted GoodSync support and they say that the speed limit is being imposed on the Google API side.  Is this true?  If so, what is the reason for limiting the speed of the Google API vs. browser uploads?  This makes using automated synchronization or file transfer tools through the API much less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true.
I doubt the reason is public, but is probably to do with concerns about abuse.