# What are some reasons why uploading to Google Drive via an API call is much slower than upload through the Chrome browser?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-drive-api

I recently have been experimenting with the Google Drive API and have been uploading large files to Google Drive by an API call and have noticed speeds around 10-15 Megabytes/second. However, when I use the Google Chrome browser to do the uploading, it dramatically goes up to something like 50 Megabytes/second. I assumed that the Chrome browser was doing the exact same thing as I was doing on my Mac OS X Terminal, is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why the upload speed using Google Drive via an API call is slower than Chrome browser is that Google Drive via API was capped to control the abuse. You can refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792206/google-drive-api-vs-browser-upload-very-slow).